# Permission error to access mounted directory in localhost

Tags: permissions, rhel, apache-httpd, chmod

OK, I formatted my flash to **ext4** file system,
changed all the permissions to **777** and mounted it to **/var/www/html/web**.

Now, when i access **localhost/web** it gives the following error:

"You don't have permission to access /web/cv on this server."

But when I normally access localhost it loads index.html that locates in /var/www/html directory, it means it has to do with mounting of flash.

Can't I hold my web directory inside my flash card in Linux?
Why it gives permission error, maybe it could be related to Apache server?
All guesses and solutions would be greatly appreciated.

BTW I am using **Redhat Linux Enterprise Server 6**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably running into SELinux issues. The directories on the flash drive probably aren't labelled such that `httpd_t` can touch them. You can do a `setenforce 0 ; service httpd restart` and attempt to access again to confirm. If that is what's going on then you can either configure SELinux to go into permissive mode (last ditch "just trying to get it to work" solution) or run a recursive `restorecon` on `/var/www`

Comment: wow, that actually worked, though i have no idea what "setenforce 0" really did:)

Comment: It temporarily switches SELinux into permissive mode, where it will log all denials but not actually deny the operations. It's just a useful command for determining if SELinux is the problem. Your issue is probably the labeling issue, in which case doing the recursive restorecon after it's mounted should cause all files and directories to be re-labeled with something SELinux will allow httpd_t processes access to.